# Javascript - Appending data on a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am currently appending my data line by line like this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < topArr.length; i++) {
        $('#oneTitle').html(topArr[0].sector)
        $('#twoTitle').html(topArr[1].sector)
        $('#threeTitle').html(topArr[2].sector)
    }
```

I am attempting to get the same result in a for loop. I am currently using 3 different id's because in this list they title's are numbered with css.

For example

1. Online Stores
2. Retail Stores
3. E-commerence

I am attempting to loop through my array and append to these 3 ids just like the code above.

Is there a way to loop increment through my array with one line of code without having to identity which index I am targeting?

I am having trouble of the JavaScript logic but I believe it is something similar to this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < topArr.length; i++) {
            $('#oneTitle').html(topArr[i].sector)
        }
```

With this only one row gets returned as I am trying to return the 3 that I have hard coded above.

Here is the html :

```
  <ul class="top-collection">
  <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">1</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="oneTitle"></h4></div></li>
  <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">2</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="twoTitle"></h4></div></li>
  <li class="top-collection-item"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><span class="data-circle">3</span><h4 class="top-table-text" id="threeTitle"></h4></div></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using jQuery you can use each() method which you can use on `$('ul.top-collection li')`. There is a good example on their web page:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.eq()` method to select an element by index.

```
$lis = $(".top-collection h4");
for (var i = 0; i < topArr.length; i++) {
    lis.eq(i).html(topArr[i].sector);
}
```

Or you can iterate over the elements:

```
lis.html(function(i) {
    return topArr[i].sector;
});
```